# Changing the case of formula output

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I'm using a JSON call to insert the city for a zip but the results are in all caps. The zip is in C2. Can I use PROPER to initial cap the results of the formula at the same time as the call so I don't have to run the formula on a different column? I know this is probably beginner stuff but, I can't figure it out.

This is what I'm using. I want to run PROPER at the same time.

```
=ImportJSON(CONCATENATE("http://ziptasticapi.com/",C2), "/city","noHeaders")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
=PROPER(ImportJSON(CONCATENATE("http://ziptasticapi.com/",C2), "/city","noHeaders"))
```

Comment: See, I knew it would be simple. Thanks!